# Strip out html from excerpt

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have created a visualforce page which displays a rich text field from my custom object, the field contains html tags for formatting which I would like to strip out as I will be cutting off the text after x characters which may cause issues if there are any unclosed html tags.

Here is my code at the moment:

```
<apex:outputText class="text-excerpt" value="{!left(article.Content__c,300)}" />
```

Comment: Have a look at [How to retrieve just the text without formatting from a rich text field using JSON?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32049/how-to-retrieve-just-the-text-without-formatting-from-a-rich-text-field-using-js)

Comment: @BarCotter I'm not really familiar with JSON and how it works with Salesforce, I was really expecting some kind of apex tag to fix this.

Comment: The title is misleading but that question is exactly what you are trying to do. Have a look at Andrew Fawcetts answer on it. There is no apex tag to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your scenario, you could try doing this (use escape attribute)

```
<apex:outputText class="text-excerpt" value="{!left(article.Content__c,300)}" escape="false" />
```

Comment: Wouldn't that do the opposite of what I want? that wont the escape the html tags which means they could be leave unclosed tags

Answer (score 2):

The System.String class has a '[stripHtmlTags](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_stripHtmlTags)' method.

> Removes HTML markup from the input string and returns the plain text.

Comment: Daniel, adding some more text or explanation will increase the meaning of your answer. For instance: I've gone ahead and included a quote out of the docmentation that you refered to.

Comment: This was my first answer so just went for it. Thank you for your help Samuel.